# Sort and move files by name (ksh)

Tags: bash, unix, ksh

This is the command for now

`#/root/scripts/<script_name>.sh $c $targetdir_dir/$i`

I need the files to be not only moved to `targetdir`, but to a certain `subfolder` of that directory.

Example:

```
emea_targetdir
usa_targetdir
```

If file name is `region1_filename_extension` the script move it to `targetdir_region1`, and if filename is `region2_filename_extension`, then to move it to `targetdir_region2`, and so on.

Comment: It’s a basic match and move script, if you want further help you should paste some code, show desired input and output, re-write the question as minimal as possible

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: The simple `mv` command should be sufficient; you will need to show why it isn't.  You can rename files with `mv`, and part of the renaming can place the file in a chosen directory.  The 'sort' in your question doesn't seem to mean "apply the `sort` command to the file" but "place the file in the correct sub-directory".

Comment: updated the original post hopefully it'll make more sense

Answer (score -1):

Try the following ksh script:-

```
#!/bin/ksh

files=`ls  *.txt`
for filename in $files
do
    dir_name=`echo $filename | cut -d'_' -f1`
    mkdir -p $dir_name
    mv $filename $dir_name/$xx
done
```

Steps:-

1. This script will read all the .txt files from current directory
2. Then split the filename with '_' character
3. After that it creates a dir with first part of name if dir does not exists.
4. Then it will copy the file to directory as per first part of filename.

Comment: Unfortuantely I have to keep the filenames, because upcoming scripts depend on that... a lot of them. Directories all exist, files just need to be thrown to the right place

Comment: `ksh` supports arrays: use them. Don't use `ls`.

Comment: @fba, the above script doesn't rename files, it just copies them to specific directories. And it also creates directories only if dir of given name doesn't exist. If there's already a dir by given name. It doesn't create directory.

Comment: Can I use this with multiple filenames? I mean can I list all region names?
(I cannot test what I do right now, will need to wait with that till tomorrow, but I want it to be more or less "together" by then). Thank you for all your help too

Comment: @fba, yes, it can be used with multiples files with different names. You can do a test run. 1. Create a copy of directory which contains similar files which you want to manage. 2. Then, place the script in the same newly copied directory. 3. Then, run the script in newly created directory. 4. Observe, the results, if everything is as expected, then run on real data folder.